# select first nth list items within a for loop

Tags: python, opc, fadecandy

What I have at the moment is the below loop which lights each led on a strand of 24 in turn.

```
while True:
    for i in range(24):
        pixels = [ (0,0,0) ] * numLEDs
        pixels[i] = (100, 100, 100)
        client.put_pixels(pixels)
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

What I would like to have is that the previously lit leds stay on for each iteration. So the number of lit leds increases by one each time round.

I assumed I could simply select from the start of the list to the i'th item as below.
However this returns a "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable".

I'm not really clear why this doesn't work.

```
while True:
    for i in range(24):
        pixels = [ (0,0,0) ] * numLEDs
        pixels[:i] = (100, 100, 100)
        client.put_pixels(pixels)
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

While I've got your attention, is there a better way to time these loops other than using time.sleep()? Although I am using threading, the sleeps still cause some delays when the led patterns change.

Comment: I think even your first snippet is perfect except that initial `pixels = [(0,0,0)] * numLEDs` should lie just before the for loop.

Comment: Stephen, I gave an answer in the understanding that you want to have two consecutive leds turned on in every moment, but now I'm not so sure about it... If I misunderstood your Q i'd be glad to remove my A. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example, the loop turns off the LEDs by setting them to (0,0,0). Instead, why not use this:

```
while True:
    for i in range(24):
        pixels = [ (100,100,100) ] * (i) + [ (0,0,0) ] * (numLEDs - i)
        client.put_pixels(pixels)
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

This sets the first `i` elements of the list to (100,100,100) then the remaining to be (0,0,0).

If i = 5 and numLEDs = 15, you will get this output:

```
[(100, 100, 100), (100, 100, 100), (100, 100, 100), (100, 100, 100), (100, 100, 100), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)]
```

As you can see, this will leave the others on.

Comment: how can I set a different colour depending on the value of i?
I've tried the below but it's rather clunky
          `  
               if i <= 8:
               pixels = [ (100,0,0) ] * (i) + [ (0,0,0) ] * (numLEDs - i)
            elif i >= 8 and not i > 16:
                pixels = [ (100,0,0) ] * 8 + [ (100,100,0) ] * (i) + [ (0,0,0) ] * (numLEDs - i + 8)
            elif i >= 16:
                pixels = [ (100,0,0) ] * 8 + [ (100,100,0) ] * 8 + [ (0,100,0) ] * (i) + [ (0,0,0) ] * (numLEDs - i + 16)
            client.put_pixels(pixels,  channel=0)
            time.sleep(0.5) 
`

Comment: @StephenHiggins hmm interesting q... Let me ponder that

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are forever overwriting your current pixel state with all zeroes. If you define the pixel structure outside of your infinite `while` loop, and then adjust one at a time only, it should fix your problem. Try something like this:

```
numLEDs = 24
pixels = [ (0,0,0) ] * numLEDs

while True:
    for i in range(numLEDs):
        pixels[i] = (100, 100, 100)
        client.put_pixels(pixels)
        time.sleep(0.02)
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub><sup>This is an answer dealing with the task of having two consecutive leds always turned on, so that if you mount your leds' array in the shape of a circle you see a double light moving on the circle with a frequency of approx 2 Hz.

I answered under a false impression of what the OP effectively asked, I have given another answer that addresses the REAL question but I'd like to leave here this answer 'cause it has its beauty, at least in the eyes of the beholder...</sup></sub>

You want to compute, using simple module arithmetic, which LED must be turned OFF and which has to be turned ON, using the trick (that I hope it is allowed under your requirements) that we start with a partially lit board.

```
# constants
ON = (100, 100, 100)
OFF = (0, 0, 0)
N = 24

# initial state of the leds
px = [ OFF ] * N
client.put_pixels(px) # no leds on

# set initial conditions for the iteration
px[0] = ON
n = -1

# the never-ending loop
while True:
    n +=1
    i, j = (n-1)%N, (n+1)%N
    px[i], px[j] = OFF, ON
    client.put_pixels(px)
    time.sleep(0.02)
```

Before the 1st iteration you have led 0 ON in the `px` list, after the 1st iteration you have 2 leds ON, in all further iterations you put one led OFF and turn another led ON, so in every moment you have 2 led ON.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to light ALL leds in a sequence, then turn them off at once etc etc etc ... etc

```
# constants
ON = (100, 100, 100)
OFF = (0, 0, 0)
N = 24

n = 0
while 1:

   if n%N == 0:
       px = [ OFF ] * N
       client.put_pixels(px)
       time.sleep(0.02)

   px[n%N] = ON
   client.put_pixels(px)
   time.sleep(0.02)

   n += 1
```